# What's the equivalent command of streaming (bash) scripts via curl to respective shell on windows?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell

For example the below script downloads a script and lets bash execute it:

```bash
curl -s -L https://example.com/script.sh | bash
```

What would be the equivalent to download a `https://example.com/script.ps1` powershell script file and let powershell execute it in the same above way bash does?

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest ... |Invoke-Expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke a web request to get the file and then execute it in the pipeline.

```
. { iwr -useb https://example.com/install.ps1 } | iex; install
```

In the command above, iwr is shorthand for Invoke-WebRequest and iex is Invoke-Expression